# Android native share menu: Detect supporting browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs

I am developing an Android app that uses a webview, which contains code as posted below.

A function shareArticle() is meant to filter browsers according to support for navigator.share (Google's API to call the native share menu) and do stuff accordingly. However nothing happens when clicking the button that calls the function, at the very least an alert prompt would be handy.

Any idea how can I make so I can share content using the native Android share screen?

```
export const shareArticle = () => {
    return AndroidNativeShare("Title", "www.google.com", 'description');
};

async function AndroidNativeShare(Title, URL, Description) {
    if (typeof navigator.share === 'undefined' || !navigator.share) {
        alert('Your browser does not support Android Native Share, it\'s tested on chrome 63+');
    } else if (window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
        alert('Android Native Share support only on Https:// protocol');
    } else {
        if (typeof URL === 'undefined') {
            URL = window.location.href;
        }
        if (typeof Title === 'undefined') {
            Title = document.title;
        }
        if (typeof Description === 'undefined') {
            Description = 'Share your thoughts about ' + Title;
        }
        const TitleConst = Title;
        const URLConst = URL;
        const DescriptionConst = Description;

        try {
            await navigator.share({title: TitleConst, text: DescriptionConst, url: URLConst});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error sharing: ' + error);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for existence of `navigator.share` is the recommended and logical solution. Unfortunately this does not seem to work in webviews. See the filed bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765923